# @Enumerated Mapping with Postgresql Enum

Tags: postgresql, jpa, enums, orm, jpql

I created a simple `entity` called `Agent` that have an enumerated `category`. I already know that `JPA` will not map this `enum` with **Postgresql** type `enum` so I tried to *force* this mapping.

## What I Have:

**Java Parts:** in the java part we've defined the `Person.java` entity and the `category` enumerated class.

*Person.java*

```
@Entity
public class Agentimplements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String code;
    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String first_name;
    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String family_name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private TypeEntree category;

}
```

*CategoryEn.java*

```
public enum CategoryEn{
    CUSTOMER,
    PROVIDER,
    DRIVER
}
```

---

**Sql Forcing:**

```
CREATE TYPE category_enum AS ENUM ('CUSTOMER','PROVIDER','DRIVER');

CREATE FUNCTION dummy_cast(varchar) RETURNS category_enum AS $$
SELECT CASE $1
    WHEN 'CUSTOMER' THEN 'CUSTOMER'::category_enum
    WHEN 'PROVIDER' THEN 'PROVIDER'::category_enum
    WHEN 'DRIVER' THEN 'DRIVER'::category_enum
END;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE CAST (varchar AS category_enum) WITH FUNCTION dummy_cast(varchar) AS ASSIGNMENT;

ALTER TABLE public.agent
ALTER COLUMN category
SET DATA TYPE category_enum
USING agent::text::category_enum;
```

---

Until here, everything is working fine, but when I try to execute this `query` in the the `AgentFacade`:

```
 String jpql ="SELECT a FROM Agent a"
                + " WHERE a.category = :cat";
        Query query = em.createQuery(jpql);
        query.setParameter("cat", CategoryEn.DRIVER);
```

I'm having the following error:

> **Caused by**: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002]
>    (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):
>    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>    Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR:  operator does not exist : category_enum= character varying
>
> **Indication** :No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts

---

My questions are:

1. Why I am having this error ?
2. Can I solve this error ? How?
3. Why the `JPA` doesn't have a tool that map automatically a Java `enum` to an Sql `type enum` ?

**PS**: I've already seen almost all the stackoverflow questions/answers that are similare to this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because your driver/ORM is likely casting that parameter to varchar.

You could create operator for that comparison:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION texteq(
    category_enum,
    text)
  RETURNS boolean AS $q$ SELECT texteq($1::text, $2) $q$
  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT
  COST 1;

CREATE OPERATOR =(
  PROCEDURE = texteq,
  LEFTARG = category_enum,
  RIGHTARG = text,
  COMMUTATOR = =,
  NEGATOR = <>,
  RESTRICT = eqsel,
  JOIN = eqjoinsel,
  HASHES,
  MERGES);
```

I didn't test if it actually works in JOIN merges/hashes, but simple comparison looks fine.

Comment: Yes, this is working very fine, but please tell me do you know **Why the JPA doesn't have a tool that map automatically a Java enum to an Sql type enum ?**

Comment: I sadly do not know nor did I find anything about it. I imagine part of the problem is that there is different implementation for enum between MySQL, PostgresSQL and MSSQL does not have it at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Łukasz